# Suspending thread execution within signal handler

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, signals

This is a bit of a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700985/is-there-a-way-to-view-the-register-contents-of-one-thread-from-another-thread-w).

Suppose I use `sigaction` to set up a signal handler of my own design.  In this signal handler, I access information about the CPU state (the thread's stack pointer, for example) and copy it to a predetermined location in memory.  I now want to examine a value on this thread's stack from another thread.

Is there a way to suspend execution of the thread in the signal handler from within the same signal handler, so that I can safely examine this thread's stack from another thread?  (Note: I define "safely" here to mean "without worrying about the thread completing or returning from a function.)

If I was outside of the signal handler, I could use `sigsupend`; however, it's not safe to use within the signal handler according to [the GNU documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sigsuspend.html).  I could also try extending a signal using the method described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389105/how-to-add-code-to-the-standard-signal-handler), but I don't think any of the standard *nix signals will help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A blocking `read` on a pipe is [async-signal-safe](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html#tag_02_04_03), and provides a convenient way to wake up your "suspended" thread.

E.g.,

```
static int the_pipe[2] = {-1, -1};  // file descriptors allocated in main via pipe()

static void
siginfo_handler(int s, siginfo_t *si, void *ctx) {
  char c;

  // do something with (ucontext_t *)ctx

  // now wait for someone else to wake us up
  read(the_pipe[0], &c, 1);

  ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - I'm looking to suspend the thread in the first place, not wake it up.  Would you mind elaborating please?

Comment: Where you'd want to `sigsuspend`, `read(pipefd, ...)` instead.  Is the modified answer clearer?  You can keep the thread suspended as long as you like, and wake it up by writing to the other end of the pipe.